# Derivative problem with inequalities on interval

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\to R$ be continuous function on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$, and let $f(0)=0$, and $|f'(x)| \le 2|f(x)|$ for all $x_0 \in (0,1)$. Prove that for all $x_0 \in (0,1)$ there exists $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $0<x_2<x_1<x_0$ and $|f(x_0)| \le 4 x_0 x_1|f(x_2)|$.
My attempt: I proved that for all $x_0$ there exists $x_2$ such that $|f(x_0)|\le 2x_0|f(x_2)|$ using Lagrange's theorem, but I'm stuck at that.

Comment: You should really try to type it up properly

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(0) = 0$, by the mean value theorem there exists $x_1\in (0,x_0)$ such that $f(x_0) = f'(x_1)x_0$. By the same theorem, there exists $x_2\in (0,x_1)$ such that $f(x_1) = f'(x_2)x_1$. Hence $0 < x_2 < x_1 < x_0$ and

$$\lvert f(x_0)\rvert = x_0\lvert f'(x_1)\rvert \le 2x_0\lvert f(x_1)\rvert = 2x_0\lvert f'(x_2)x_1\rvert \le 4x_0x_1\lvert f(x_2)\rvert.$$